# cout a stringstream twice ends up in corrupted cout (minimal example)

Tags: c++, cout, stringstream, streambuf

I have the following code, and I dont quite understand why the results happens to be like the one below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
int main () {

   std::stringstream s;

   std::streambuf *backup;
   backup = cout.rdbuf();


   s << "Oh my god" << endl;


   cout << "Before1" << endl;
       cout << s.rdbuf();
   cout << "After1" << endl;


   cout << "Before2" << endl;
   //s.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg); // If that is in: After 2 is printed!
   cout << s.rdbuf();
   //cout.rdbuf(backup); // If that is in, also After 2 is printed!
   cout << "After2" << endl;

}
```

**Output:**

```
Before1
Oh my god
After1
Before2
```

Where is the rest??¿ It only gets outputted when We uncomment the above lines...
What happens internally? Does anybody know? =) Would be interesting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check whether the fail bit is set on `cout`.  You could also just clear the fail bit, with `cout.clear()`.

---

Here's the rule from the Standard (section 27.7.3.6.3) that requires that the fail bit will be set in this case:

> `basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(basic_streambuf<charT,traits>* sb);`
>
> Effects:  Behaves as an unformatted output function.   After the sentry object is constructed, if `sb` is null calls `setstate(badbit)` (which may throw `ios_base::failure`).
>
> Gets characters from `sb` and inserts them in `*this`.  Characters are read from `sb` and inserted until any of the following occurs:
>
> - end-of-file occurs on the input sequence;
> - inserting in the output sequence fails (in which case the character to be inserted is not extracted);
> - an exception occurs while getting a character from `sb`.
>
> **If the function inserts no characters, it calls `setstate(failbit)`** (which may throw `ios_base::failure`). If an exception was thrown while extracting a character, the function sets `failbit` in error state, and if `failbit` is on in `exceptions()` the caught exception is rethrown.
>
> Returns: `*this`.

Comment: This is likely it, the libstdc++ documentation has this to say about the `__ostream_type&
      operator<<(__streambuf_type* __sb);`  "If the function inserts no characters, failbit is set." Which seems plausible, since the `s.rdbuf()` would be positioned at its end the 2. time one tries to print it.

Comment: Oh, thanks ! That was the point! Where can we read in the libstdc++ docu?

Comment: @Gabriel: This is described in section 27.7.3.6.3 in the Standard.